# Keeping the path of BFS search

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

Given a maze, start coordinate, and end coordinate,

```
maze = [
    [BLACK, BLACK, WHITE, WHITE],
    [BLACK, WHITE, WHITE, WHITE],
    [WHITE, WHITE, BLACK, WHITE],
    [WHITE, WHITE, BLACK, WHITE],
]
s = Coordinate(3, 0)
e = Coordinate(0, 3)
```

I am trying to find the path from start to end using BFS.
Finding the path is straightforward, but I am struggling with keeping the path to the destination.
What I've tried is

```
directions = [(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]
queue = collections.deque()
queue.append(s)
path = []
while queue:
    curr = queue.popleft()
    if curr == e:
        path.append(curr)
        return path
    path.append(curr)
    maze[curr.x][curr.y] = BLACK
    for x, y in directions:
        new_x, new_y = curr.x + x, curr.y + y
        if new_x < 0 or new_y < 0 or new_x >= len(maze) or new_y >= len(maze[0]) or maze[new_x][new_y] == BLACK:
            continue
        queue.append(Coordinate(new_x, new_y))
```

Something like this, but the result prints out all the nodes that I've visited, instead of the final path. Any tips on keeping the right path and removing the node that does not belong to the final path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of maintaining a `path` list, you can maintain an `edge_to` dictionary which keeps track of which previous vertex led to visiting a certain vertex. Whenever you add something to your queue, you can can update `edge_to`. A modified version of your function using this approach is as follows:

```
Coordinate = collections.namedtuple('Coordinate', ['x', 'y'])

def find_path(s, e):
    directions = [(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]
    queue = collections.deque()
    queue.append(s)
    edge_to = {s: None}

    while queue:
        curr = queue.popleft()
        if curr == e:
            return path(edge_to, curr)
        maze[curr.x][curr.y] = BLACK
        for x, y in directions:
            new_x, new_y = curr.x + x, curr.y + y
            if new_x < 0 or new_y < 0 or new_x >= len(maze) or new_y >= len(maze[0]) or maze[new_x][new_y] == BLACK:
                continue
            c = Coordinate(new_x, new_y)
            edge_to[c] = curr
            queue.append(c)
```

Notice the call to `path(...)` when you find your end vertex. That function just builds a list from the `edge_to` dictionary:

```
def path(edge_to, end):
    curr = end
    res = []
    while curr != None:
        res.append(curr)
        curr = edge_to[curr]
    return list(reversed(res))
```

For your given maze, and start and end coordinates, we get the following output:

```
s = Coordinate(3, 0)
e = Coordinate(0, 3)
print(find_path(s, e))
```

**Output**

```
[Coordinate(x=3, y=0), Coordinate(x=2, y=0), Coordinate(x=2, y=1), Coordinate(x=1, y=1), Coordinate(x=1, y=2), Coordinate(x=0, y=2), Coordinate(x=0, y=3)]
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems solid. Is this the most optimal way to keep track of the path though?

Comment: @Dawn17 Yes I think so because you don't know what the path is until you reach the end coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for x, y in directions:
    new_x, new_y = curr.x + x, curr.y + y
    if new_x < 0 or new_y < 0 or new_x >= len(maze) or new_y >= len(maze[0]) or maze[new_x][new_y] == BLACK:
        continue
    queue.append(Coordinate(new_x, new_y))
```

your `queue.append(Coordinate(new_x, new_y))` is running everytime your for loops iterates.

We want this condition to only happen when our if condition runs, so lets try something like this:

```py
for x, y in directions:
    new_x, new_y = curr.x + x, curr.y + y
    if new_x < 0 or new_y < 0 or new_x >= len(maze) or new_y >= len(maze[0]) or maze[new_x][new_y] == BLACK:
        queue.append(Coordinate(new_x, new_y))
        continue
```

When our if-condition is met, append it, and then continue. Let me know if this helps.